# Batch multiline start string

Tags: batch-file

I want to be able to have this command in multiline :

**What I have :**

start cmd.exe /k "first line, second line"

**What I want :**

start cmd.exe /k "

first line

second line"

Comment: End the first line with `^`, then continue with the next...

Comment: `C:\>cmd /k < ListofCommands.txt`

Comment: Entering one line to run multiple commands is literally what batch files were created for.  `cmd /k ListofCommands.bat`

Answer (score 4):

I think you want something like this:

```
cmd /K ^
  first line ^
  second line
```

Assuming both `first line` and `second line` are commands, you need to use the `&` operator:

```
cmd /K ^
  first line ^& ^
  second line
```

The `&` must be escaped here like `^&`, otherwise the lines were read as two commands `cmd /K first line` and `second line`.

Answer (score 0):

Easy use this: `&`

```
/k "command 1 & command 2 & command 3"
```